# Como limpar somente a aba atual!

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um menu de abas, e gostaria de limpar (refresh) só na aba em que estou, mantendo os dados das outras.

Menu:

```
<body onLoad="AlternarAbas('td_cada','div_cada')">
<table width="100%" height="100"  align="left" valign="top" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-left: 1px solid #0000FF;">
    <tr>
        <td style="border-color:blue"  height="20" width="50" class="menu" id="td_cada" onClick="AlternarAbas('td_cada','div_cada')">Incluir</td>
        <td style="border-color:blue"  height="20" width="50" class="menu" id="td_cons" onClick="AlternarAbas('td_cons','div_cons')">Consultar</td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td height="200" style="border-color:blue"  width="300" class="tb-conteudo" valign="top" colspan="2" >
        <div id="div_cada" width="100" class="conteudo" style="display: block; padding-top:5px;">
            <table border="0" width="50%">
                <tr>
                    <td >
                        <iframe style="border-radius:20px;"  scrolling="no" src="../sai_cada_usua/sai_frm_incl_usua.php" width="830" height="310" >
                        </iframe>
                    </td>
                </tr>
          </table>
       </div>

        <div id="div_cons" class="conteudo" style="display: block; padding-top:5px;">
            <table border="0" width="50%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <form>
                            <button type="button" value="Atualizar" style="height:26" style="width:5"  size="10" onclick='javascript:parent.location.replace("../sai_cada_usua/sai_cons_usua.php")' width="830" height="300" >
                                                                    <image src="../sai_imag/refresh.ico"> </button>
                        </form>
                        <iframe style="border-radius:20px;" scrolling="" src="../sai_cada_usua/sai_cons_usua.php" width="830" height="290" >
                        </iframe>
                    </td>
                </tr>
          </table>
       </div>
```

Nessa div ~> `<div id="div_cons" class="conteudo" style="display: block; padding-top:5px;">`, eu tenho um `button` que faz a chamada da tela novamente ("um `atualizar`"). Mas, como ele chama todas as telas, ele apaga o que pode ter de conteúdo nas outras. Existe alguma maneira de fazer um `refresh` só nela? Algum botão específico, etc?

exemplo : [JSF](http://jsfiddle.net/qf88E/2/)

Comment: você deve utilizar ajax, para trocar o conteúdo de uma única aba dinamicamente fazendo assim o refresh

Comment: Hum' obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa inserir (preferencialmente em um arquivo .JS separado) o script a seguir, que implementa a técnica popularmente conhecida como AJAX.

```
function atualizar(divResultado, url){

    // Conforme tutorial da W3Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById(divResultado).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Então, basta modificar seu `<button>` para chamar esta nova funcionalidade:

```
<button type="button" value="Atualizar" style="height:26" style="width:5" size="10" onclick="atualizar('div_cons', '../sai_cada_usua/sai_cons_usua.php');" width="830" height="300">
    <image src="../sai_imag/refresh.ico">
</button>
```

Lembrando que, se houver um botão similar na `sai_cons_usua.php`, você também deve atualizá-lo.

Caso necessário, [aqui está o teste](http://jsfiddle.net/ruipimentel/LNTXx/) que eu fiz no JSFiddle. Espero que ajude!